# How can javascript be a synchronous language and run asynchronously in browser and in node.js enviroment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, v8, execution

I mean what is the actual difference? I know that it is both interpreted in the browser and the node.js enviroment by the Google v8 engine? So what am I missing here? How can the same code be executed differently?

How can the same language be synchronous and asynchronous together?

Comment: its **not** synchronous in browsers too

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Isn't javascript synchronous and single-threaded as a language?

Comment: @dimrizo: The **language** is entirely silent on the topic of threading, so it's up to the environment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder friend, can you suggest any good reads about the topic of threading?

Answer (score 3):

> How can javascript run synchronous in the browser and asynchronoously in Node.js enviroment?

It doesn't. It runs in a single-threaded*, event-driven manner in both environments. When processing a task (e.g., responding to something that happened), that thread does things synchronously. One of the things it can do (in both environments) is schedule an asynchronous callback to be processed after the current task completes.

> How can the same language be synchronous and asynchronous together?

Synchronous vs. asynchronous processing is mostly a matter of environment rather than language. Some languages have features designed to make it easier to use them in *multi-threaded* environments (as distinct from synchronous/asynchronous ones), and some may have async features built in, but if the language doesn't (and JavaScript doesn't), the environment can provide them.

For example: JavaScript has no way built-in way to schedule an asynchronous callback**. But browsers provide the `setTimeout` function that does exactly that (as does Node, which also provides `nextTick` and various others).

---

* Except that browsers can fire up multiple threads via [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) (and Node code can spawn child processes).

** ES6's promises will change that; *resolving* or *rejecting* an ES6 promise is inherently an asynchronous operation (more on that [here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-objects), [here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-resolve-functions), and [here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-jobs-and-job-queues)).

Comment: I have written a whole web application in node.js with 100 visits per day but I still find it hard to understand the callback and the asynchronous nature. Maybe because I am a self-taught programmer.